# JS documentation: Define function parameter as instance of a class

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Let's say there is a function that has the parameter `element`.

```
/**
 * Function's description ...
 * 
 * @param {*} element 
 * Element description ....
 * 
 * @returns {Boolean}
 * Result description ....
 */
function myFunction(element) {
    return true;
}
```

The parameter `element` need to be an instance of the (*custom*) class `MySpecialButton`.
So that `if( element instanceof MySpecialButton)` would return `true`.

```
class MySpecialButton{
    constructor(){
    }
    // Methods ...
}
```

So I tried to define the parameter `element` by typing it's class name.

```
 * @param {MySpecialButton} element 
 * Element description ....
```

But when I type the function in Visual Studio Code, the help says **any**.

```
myFunction(element: any): boolean
```

So how do I define a function parameter as an instance of a javascript class?
The class `MySpecialButton` and the function mentioned above are not defined in the same JS file.

Comment: It works fine for me, if `MySpecialButton` is defined in the same file

Comment: The class is defined in a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the class first, then you'll be able to reference it in JSDoc:

```
// MySpecialButton.js

module.exports = class MySpecialButton{
    constructor(){
    }
    // Methods ...
}
```

and

```
const MySpecialButton = require('./MySpecialButton');
/**
 * Function's description ...
 * 
 * @param {MySpecialButton} element 
 * Element description ....
 * 
 * @returns {Boolean}
 * Result description ....
 */
function myFunction(element) {
    return true;
}
```